# How to call value of textbox in View in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do i send the value of my textbox "Name" to parameters of my submit button. I know this is newbie question. I really have no experience in MVC 4. I appreciate your help and understanding :) thanks

```
@Html.TextBox("Name")

using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Warehouse", new { page = ViewBag.page, name=(textbox)  }, FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                        <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign your value to a model and put your textbox inside the form so when you click the submit button it will be passed to your action method.

Your view should look something like this:

```
@model YouProjectName.Models.WarehouseModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
   <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

your action method would be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(WarehouseModel model)
    {
       var strname=model.Name;
             return View();
    }
```

and your model should look something like this.

```
public class WarehouseModel
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of m in (m => m.Name)?

Comment: it's a linq expression saying that your assigning the value of the textbox to the model property "Name".

Comment: if its aligned to your original question then its okay.